# DSE Cluster node disk gets filled

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I have an 6 node cluster , each node is of 1000 GB in size. But the size of one node reached to 1000 GB randomly.On analysis i found only one key space gets filled & only 1 table of this keyspace size get increased from 200 GB to 800 GB (In 24 hours ) , which means someone execute operations on this table only . I want to figure out what operations had perform on this node which leads to this size increment ? 
Are there any logs which can be looked at to see what operations were performed?

Answer (score 1):

I guess how I would do this is to use "nodetool tablehistograms" to prove that you have large partitions for the table. Then I would go to the table directory and run "sstablemetadata" on some of the data files, locating ones that displays some large partition sizes.

One trick you could do once you find sstables that have larger partitions is:

```
sstabledump <sstable> | grep  -n "\"key\" :"
```

What that will do is show you the line number every time the key switches, the larger the gap between lines, the more rows there are.

Here is an example:

```
sstabledump aa-483-bti-Data.db | grep  -n "\"key\" :"
4:      "key" : [ "PROCESSING" ],
65605:      "key" : [ "PENDING" ],
8552007:      "key" : [ "COMPLETED" ],
```

As you can see, the gap between PENDING and COMPLETED was much larger than PROCESSING and PENDING (65k lines v.s. 8M lines). So this tells me that the PROCESSING partition is relatively small compared to PENDING. The only mystery is how large is the COMPLETED one as there is no "ending" line. To get the total line count, run:

```
sstabledump aa-483-bti-Data.db | wc -l
16316029
```

Total line count is 16M. So COMPLETED goes from 8M to 16M, or about 8M lines. So the COMPLETED partition is large as well, about as large as the PENDING partition.

Looking at sstablemetadata to see if that matches up with the output, I see that it does:

```
sstablemetadata aa-483-bti-Data.db
Partition Size:
   Size (bytes)         | Count  (%)  Histogram
   943127 (921.0 kB)    |     1 ( 33) OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
   129557750 (123.6 MB) |     1 ( 33) OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
   155469300 (148.3 MB) |     1 ( 33) OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

I see two relatively large partitions and one small one. Bingo.

Maybe some of those can help you get to the bottom of your large partition(s).

Comment: Thanks Jim, but how can i get the query here , as i want to know whether user perform insert or delete with what data ?

Comment: There is no way to get the actual query that executed unless it ran slowly or trace was enabled. Unfortunately this capability does not exist. sstabledump will show you whether the record was inserted or deleted. If you find the big partition with the above, you can dump between the lines to see what was going on. If you don't see deletes, then it was either inserts or updates - which is always inserts anyways. At least you know which partition was problematic. Maybe you can reach out to the app folks to find out what may have happened for the affected partitions.

Answer (score 1):

With DataStax Enterprise, you should be able to turn on the [Database Auditing](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.7/security/secAuditEnable.html) feature.  In fact, by configuring a logger class of `CassandraAuditWriter`, all activity gets written to the `audit_log` table in the `dse_audit` keyspace.

The data is organized by this PRIMARY KEY: ((date, node, day_partition), event_time); and has columns like `username`,`table_name`,`keyspace_name`,`operation` and others.

Check out the [DataStax docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.7/security/secAuditEnable.html) on that for configuration and query options.

As for (open source) Apache Cassandra, we use [Ericsson's Cassandra Audit](https://github.com/Ericsson/ecaudit) plugin for this functionality.  By adding in the project's JAR, and making a couple of adjustments to the `cassandra.yaml` file, you can view the `audit.log`s for records like:

```
15:42:41.655 - client:'10.0.110.1'|user:'flynn'|status:'ATTEMPT'|operation:'DELETE FROM ecks.ectbl WHERE partk = ?'
```